# Can you use an undefined type in a C++ template function if the function is never used?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a conversion function between objects of two classes (Eigen::Vector3d and MyVector, a Protocol Buffers message), but I want to delay evaluation of the function body until the function is referenced (at which point both classes would be defined).

The function should be callable in files that later define both classes, and it should not cause a compilation error if the function is never used.

I have:

```
#include <Eigen/Core> // defines Eigen::Vector3d

class MyVector {
  public: int set_x(int x) { x_ = x; }
  private: int x_;
}

void operator<< (MyVector &msg, const Eigen::Vector3d &vec) {
  msg.set_x(vec.x());
}
```

which I use as:

```
MyVector msg;
Eigen::Vector3d vec(1, 2, 3);
msg << vec;
```

This works fine if the function is defined after MyVector, but I would like to be able to define the function such that it can be included in a translation unit that lacks the MyVector class.

I could change the function to this:

```
template<typename Msg>
void operator<< (Msg &msg, ...
```

but this is unacceptable because it would apply to other message classes:

```
quaternion_msg << Eigen::Vector3d(1, 2, 3);   // quaternion has xyz but also w!
```

and I want that to cause a build error.

Is there some kind of template magic that can do that? If not, is there a better way to provide this operator short of adding MyVector to the header file (or its dependencies)?

Comment: Why not put the operator << as a member of MyVector?

Comment: "but I would like to be able to define the function such that it can be included in a translation unit that lacks the MyVector class." Are you trying to use the void operator<< (MyVector &msg, const Eigen::Vector3d &vec) without the MyVector class definition

Comment: you can create a template specialization for type MyVector and for the generic template stub just add code which would result in a  compile error.

Comment: The easiest way to is use MACRO magic. Use the same sentry macro in MyVector.h to define the required function.

Comment: @goldcode Template specialization for functions is not valid.

Comment: I have to ask: why do you want to be able to include this header if you don't have the MyVector class?

Comment: @Xiaoge Su why not? See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: @XiaogeSu I can't change MyVector. It's a generated class (from Protocol Buffers).

Comment: @ali I want to be able to define it without the MyVector definition, but if I were going to actually use it, I would define MyVector first.

Comment: @goldcode I don't see how I can create the specialization without having defined MyVector first.

Comment: @egur I can't modify myvector.h (though I guess I could wrap it in another header). I also would like a user to be able to include myvector.h before including whatever file defines the operator.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak I want the function to be available wherever both MyVector and Vector3d are defined, but I also want other files to be able to include either one of those files without including the other. A better example would probably have used a custom class, instead of Eigen::Vector3d. I'm actually looking for a solution that works with the combination of a class I've defined and an autogenerated class.

Comment: @goldcode http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @Xiaoge Su All it mentions is - depending on the order function templates and thier specializations are written, template overloads unexpected by the user could be used. That does not render function template specialization as invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use undefined types or functions in function templates as long as they depend somehow on a template argument and are defined at the point of instantation: non-dependent names are looked up at the pointer where the function template is defined. Dependent names are looked up at the point of instantiation (assuming two-phase name look-up is correctly implemented).

The other side, preventing successful instantiation with other types than a small set of selected types could probably be done using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error):

```
class MyVector;
template <typename Msg>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Msg, MyVector>::value>::type
operator<< (Msg& msg, Eigen::Vector3d const& vec) {
    msg.set_x(vec.x);
}
```

The `type` of `std::enable_if<F, T>` is only defined if `F` is `true` (and `T` is defaulted to `void`). Since `std::is_same<Msg, MyVector>::value` becomes `true` only when `Msg` is `MyVector` this operator only gets defined when instantiated with `MyVector`. On the other hand, it gets defined when instantiated a which point `MyVector` is hopefully defined.

However, since `MyVector` is named in the interface, its name needs to be declared although it doesn't needed to be defined. It is possible to avoid this need if `MyVector` could specialize a trait in which case naming `MyVector` a type can be delayed until it is defined and the trait is specialized instead. Doing something like this may be important if `MyVector` actually happens be a template with defaulted arguments as these can't be forward declared.

Comment: This fits my requirements perfectly and now I know about lots of new [type operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) that I had missed in C++11. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a small templatized class that is specialized and use that within the templatized operator << function.

ie:

```
template <typename MSG>
struct Convertor;  // generic causes compiler error

template<>
struct Convertor<MyVector> {
  static void Convert(MyVector msg, Eigen::vector3d const& vec) {
    msg.set_x(vec.x());  
  }
};

template<typename Msg>
void operator<< (Msg &msg, const Eigen::Vector3d &vec) {
  Convertor<Msg>::Convert(msg, vec);
}
```

You can expand this pattern to more template parameters if needed and specialize for only the conversions you want.

Comment: I tried a similar specialization with just one function and got incomplete-type errors. I have the same problem with the code you posted. I'll include the code I tried in the next comment. I replaced the Eigen class to simplify it a bit. Here is the error I get when the message class is not defined:

    `test.cc: In static member function ‘static void Convertor<MyMsg>::Convert(MyMsg&, const NotAMessage&)’:
    test.cc:19:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class MyMsg’
    msg.set_x(vec.x());  
    test.cc:11:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class MyMsg’
    class MyMsg;
          ^`

Comment: // class MyMsg {
// public: int set_x(int x) { x_ = x; }
// private: int x_;
// };

class NotAMessage {
public: int x() const { return x_; }
private: int x_;
};

class MyMsg;

template <typename MSG>
struct Convertor;  // generic causes compiler error

template<>
struct Convertor<MyMsg> {
  static void Convert(MyMsg& msg, NotAMessage const& vec) {
    msg.set_x(vec.x());  
  }
};

template<typename Msg>
void operator<< (Msg &msg, const NotAMessage &vec) {
  Convertor<Msg>::Convert(msg, vec);
}

Comment: You should place the specialization with the class MyVector